# CART always giving the same prediction in classification

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, cart, scikit-learn

I have a couple of models (Decision Trees with depths 3 and 6, using sklearn's `DeccisionTreeClassifier`) that I have trained on an N label data set. I have performed a K fold cross validation on them and it gave me satisfactory accuracy levels.

But when I give just one record for prediction, it always ends up giving me the same answer, irrespective of changing the key attributes. E.g. if I have one row identified by a set of attributes A, it predicts a label X. Now I change a couple of attributes (based on their importance) in a copy-pasted version of the first row. Now the first row still gets X but the second row gets Y. I then delete the first row and to my surprise, the second row which is now the first and only row returns X!

I felt it was a case of overfitting but then it should never give me two different labels for the same record, right? I haven't seen too many examples/blogs/resources of single record tests for machine learning algorithms. Can anyone please explain or point me to one of them?

Comment: can you post some code to help you better?